# get custom fieds in rest API (meta_key)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have this function to for my custom fields to save in WP data base (this is working and saving):

```
function notifyem_save_post() {
    if(empty($_POST)) return; //why is prefix_teammembers_save_post triggered by add new? 
    global $post;
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "country", $_POST["country"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "region", $_POST["region"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "time", $_POST["time"]);
    update_post_meta($post->ID, "activity", $_POST["activity"]);
}
```

I want to display them from REST API but only TITLE is showing:

```
[{"title":"john"},{"title":"xxx"},{"title":"11"}]
```

This is my code for my REST API GET

```
function notifyem_rest_get() {
    $subscriptions = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'notifyem'
    ));
    $subscriptionResults = array();
    register_rest_route('notifyemAPI/v1', '/subscription', array(
        'methods' => WP_REST_SERVER::READABLE,
        'callback' => array($this, 'getSubscription')
    ));
}

function getSubscription() {
    $subscriptions = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'notifyem',
        'meta_key' => 'country'
    ));

    $subscriptionResults = array();

    while($subscriptions->have_posts()) {
        $subscriptions->the_post();
        array_push($subscriptionResults, array(
            'region' => get_field('regi'),
            'country' => get_field('country'),
            'activity' => get_field('activity'),
            'time' => get_field('time')
        ));
    }
    return $subscriptionResults;
}
```

The screenshow below are the fields inserted to my custom post type.

[image]

Any ideas how to get the custom fields I created in my REST API?

Comment: please post yout API endpoint

Comment: @vel here is my localhsot end point API: localhost/wordpress2/wp-json/notifyemAPI/v1/subscription    <-- this is working because it shows [{"title":"john"},{"title":"xxx"},{"title":"11"}]    <--- problem is my custom fields are not showing

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 function getSubscription() {
    $subscriptions = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'notifyem',
        'meta_key' => 'country'
    ));

    $subscriptionResults = array();

    while($subscriptions->have_posts()) {
        $subscriptions->the_post();
        array_push($subscriptionResults, array(
            'region' =>  get_post_meta(the_ID(), "region", true),
            'country' =>get_post_meta(the_ID(), "country", true),
            'activity' => get_post_meta(the_ID(), "activity", true),
            'time' => get_post_meta(the_ID(), "time", true)
        ));
    }
    return $subscriptionResults;
}
```